# Authentication in Django during GET request

Tags: android, django, api, get, request

I need to do a GET request to my Django server through an android application.
The problem is that this GET function is written in Django with a @login_required.

What kind of request should i do to login and perform the GET request?

My API:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse,HttpResponseServerError, HttpResponseBadRequest
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from .models import Order, New
import json
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from .forms import NewForm
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from .validation import *
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
@login_required
@api_view(['GET'])
def get_order(request):

    order_list = Order.objects.values("user_name",
                        "user_surname",
                        "order_date").all()

    return HttpResponse(json.dumps([x for x in order_list])
```

My urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

app_name = 'API'
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^order', views.order, name='order'),
    url(r'^get_order', views.get_order, name='get_order')]
```

and:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from . import settings
from django.views.static import serve
from django.urls import path, include, re_path
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from API.views import index

urlpatterns = [
    path('API/', include('API.urls',namespace="API")),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', index, name='index'),
    path(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
    re_path(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', serve, {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT})
]
```

In Postman i'm performing a GET (http://127.0.0.1:8000/API/get_order) with basic auth, receiving `302` status code.

Comment: maybe you need to build RESTFul API with [django-rest-framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/). There are several approaches for client authentication in DRF, eg. `TokenAuthentication`. If you don't want to build RESTFul API, you need to leverage the `WebView` to access your django website instead.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how this can be done in ***Android side***, but the basic idea is that you should add ***authentication credentials*** in your *GET request*.
I'll show you an example of the same by using [***Python's `Requests` library***](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/authentication/#basic-authentication)

```
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
import requests

requests.get('http://my/url/end/poin/', auth=HTTPBasicAuth('my_username', 'mypass'))
```

[May be these results will help you to find the answer](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=basic+http+authentication+android+site:stackoverflow.com&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjk366f_sXdAhWLrY8KHXujDEIQrQIoBDAAegQICRAM&biw=1366&bih=648) ;)

**UPDATE**
1. go to **Authorization** tab
2. choose **Basic Auth** type
3. Provide your `username` and `password` in respective text boxes
4. hit the *send* button

[image]

**UPDATE-2**
change your view as below

```
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view, permission_classes
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
from rest_framework.response import Response


@permission_classes((IsAuthenticated,))
@api_view(['GET'])
def get_order(request):
    order_list = Order.objects.values("user_name",
                                      "user_surname",
                                      "order_date").all()

    return Response(data=[x for x in order_list])
```

Comment: Thank you but unfortunatly i got status error  HTTP/1.1" 302 0

Comment: Pls do add the corresponding view to the question

Comment: Seems like you are mixing plain Dango views with DRF views. Pls add the *imports* statement also

Comment: And, add your urls.py tooo

Comment: For testing purpos, comment out all url patterns **other than** `path('API/'.....)` and `url('get_order'.....)` and then try in Postman

Comment: I can't help you now, Please be patient till tomorrow (IST)

Comment: @Dev9977 I've updated the answer (*UPDATE-2* section)

Comment: Thank you. Using @permission_classes((IsAuthenticated,)), i get "method POST not allowed"

Comment: you are sending request as ***HTTP POST***, make it as **GET** method

Comment: Does this mean that @login_required (if not using DRF) wont work but the IsAuthenticated MixIn with DRF will work?