# Django passthrough API request to hide credentials

Tags: python, django

I need to make a request to b.com/rest/foo to get json data for my application. I want to do it this way to protect the credentials rather than expose them on every page.

I found [Consume an API in Django REST, server side, and serve it ,client side, in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65671134/2193381) and the corresponding answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/65672890/2193381 to be a great starting point.

I created a local url to replicate the data that the external server will return and then tried the following

```py
import requests
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.views.decorators.cache import never_cache


@never_cache
@login_required
def fakedata(request, item):
    return JsonResponse({'item': item})


def getdata(request, item):
    url = f"http://localhost:8080/rest/{item}"

    username = os.getenv('SITE_USERNAME', None)
    password = os.getenv('SITE_PASSWORD', None)

    userpass = dict(username=username, password=password)

    data = requests.get(
        url,
        auth=requests.auth.HTTPBasicAuth(**userpass),
    )

    if data is not None and data.status_code == 200:
        try:
            return JsonResponse(data.json(), safe=False)
        except ValueError:
            print("!JSON")
            return JsonResponse({})

    print("!data")
    return JsonResponse({})
```

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('rest/<str:item>', fakedata),
    path('foo/<str:item>', getdata),
]
```

When I test it with

```sh
python manage.py runserver 8080
```

and call `http://localhost:8080/foo/a`, I am getting back the html of the login page and not the data from `http://localhost:8080/rest/a` that I am expecting.

What changes do I need to make to get it to work?

Comment: you should to check this one. https://stackoverflow.com/q/52396510/9310776

Comment: Thanks. I checked it out. It calls for a DRF mixin. It feels excessive to install DRF just to use the IsAuthenticated Mixin. And also raises the question of -- what is the difference between @login_required and IsAuthenticated?

Answer (score 0):

I just went through Django documentation and found [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/#how-to-log-a-user-in) useful and working.

you can first authenticate the user by using the `authenticate()` method then login with `request` and call your `fakedata()` function with passing the `request`:

```py
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
user = authenticate(request, **userpass)
if user is not None:
    login(request, user)
    data = fakedata(request, item)
else:
    pass
```